# how to create dnn Module in visual Studio 2015

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am new developer in DNN. but I create a new Module in C#. How can i solve "Msbulid.Community.tasks.XmlReal"" error during when I release mode build.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though Visual Studio did not download the nuget package for MSBuildTasks.  Right click on the project, click "Manage Nuget Packages".  If MSBuildTasks does not show as installed, Browse for it by name and install the version 1.4.0.128. After installing do a Release Build again.

Answer (score 0):

As you're new to DNN, be sure to also check out creating Apps in 2sxc. It's like modules, just much easier and has much more pre-built like image-handling, data import/export and more.